# run stored proc over resultset

Tags: sql-server, t-sql

Is it possible to run a stored procedure for each record against a resultset?

For example,

```
Select * from Customers
```

for each record in the results above execute my stored procedure.

And also (not really important if not possible), have all this inside a main stored procedure?

Answer (score -1, accepted):

Being that cursors are inefficient, it would probably be a better idea to return your results from the Select * from customers query to your code base and loop through the results in your code to call the other procedure.

Comment: I don't think this would bypass the main issue with cursors, which is that SQL is inefficient processing row-by-row.  you're just passing the rows in from the calling application instead of from within SQL.

Comment: FYI I didn't downvote, but I'll upvote to counteract since I don't feel it was warranted.

Comment: What you are offering is even more inefficient than cursor.

Answer (score 3):

You might be better using a [User Defined Function](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ms186755.aspx) if you are not inserting / updating.
Otherwise a [cursor](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ms180169.aspx) or a [while](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ms178642.aspx) loop to iterate through each row. This will probably lead to poor performing code, and/or not be optimised by SQL very well.